# IntelliJ IDEA highlight analyzer suggestions in diff view

Tags: intellij-idea, diff, highlight

Before commit, i check changes in diff view. Unfortunatelly, diff view doesn't show warning and other inspector suggestions in changed lines. They all overridden by blue color.

warning:
[image]

change line - no warning in diff view.
[image]

How to make warnings visible in changed lines in diff view?

Answer (score 1):

There is an option to enable inspections in the diff view:

[image: diff inspections]

Comment: Thanks for your answer! This feature is turned on, i see warnings in not changed lines. But i want also see warnings in changed lines. I add pictures to question.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be possible, request is welcome at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like IntelliJ only does code analysis on the local code, so this process seems to work:

1. Check out the latest commit on the branch you'd like to compare
2. Under Window menu > Git > Show git log, find the commit that your branch was created from
3. Right-click the commit > Compare with local
4. You'll see a list of changes.  You can double-click a file to open up the diff viewer.  Warnings and suggestions should appear in the right-hand side, which is the local version.  You can also right-click on the root folder and choose "Show Diff" to go through all changes.